# wordpress upload media http error when size over 20~30KB

Tags: wordpress, http, post, upload, media

my wordpress will have http error when uploading media. After some testing that I found out all files above 30KB will have this error while size below 30KB will be more likely to be successfully uploaded (but still some small files like 6KB size will also have http error as well)

I have done a few search and below fixed has already been done:

1. configure php.ini

   ```
   post_max_size=300M
   upload_max_filesize=300M
   memory_limit=1024M
   ```

   You can find the [phpinfo](http://ic-en.ucas.ac.cn/phpinfo.php) here.
2. in wp-config.php

   ```
   define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M')
   ```
3. in theme functions.php

   ```
   add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'change_graphic_lib' );
   function change_graphic_lib($array) {
   return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
   }
   ```
4. add in .htaccess

   ```
   <IfModule mod_security.c>
   SecFilterEngine Off
   SecFilterScanPOST Off
   </IfModule>
   ```
5. add in httpd.conf

   ```
   <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
   MaxRequestLen 20000000
   </IfModule>
   ```

still the problem is the same, and I still could not upload media normally.

Also I noticed that I could not submit new post which have large text content, I guess it is due to the same issue that the size of the post request is limited.

However I have already changed the post_max_size=300M, so I don't know what causes this issue now.

Comment: What wordpress version are you using? Have you checked file permission on /uploads/ folder?

Comment: I am using the latest version 4.7.3 and uploads folder permission is already set to allow

Comment: found out that my service provider has firewall policies to block the post request. Issue fixed....